# A limit coming from some fake ellipses

Tags: calculus

Compute
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\Big(1+\alpha^\frac{2n}{n-1}\Big)^\frac{1}{2n}-\alpha^\frac{1}{n-1}}{\Big(1+\alpha^\frac{2n}{n-1}\Big)^\frac{1}{2n}-1}
$$
Some context. This will describe the behaviour of the points $(x_n,y_n), x_n>0,y_n>0$, in the fake ellipse
$C: (x/a)^{2n}+(y/b)^{2n}=1$ at maximum distance from the origin. They go to the vertex $(a,b)$ of the rectangle inscribing $C$, but the thing is to find the limit tangent of the path they follow. The limit above for $\alpha=b/a<1$ gives that limit tangent. For instance, if the limit is $+\infty$, then the limit tangent is $(0,1)$; if the limit is $1$, the limit tangent is $(a,b)/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. These are the bounds of the possible limits. By compactness, we know that the sequence must have convergent subsequences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a variable $x=\frac{1}{2n}\to0$, and the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\Big(1+\alpha^\frac{2}{1-2x}\Big)^x-\alpha^\frac{2x}{1-2x}}{\Big(1+\alpha^\frac{2}{1-2x}\Big)^x-1}.
$$
It is of the form $0/0$, hence we use l'Hôpital. First we compute the derivative of 
$$
f(x)=\Big(1+\alpha^\frac{2}{1-2x}\Big)^x=e^{x\log(1+\alpha^\frac{2}{1-2x})}.
$$
We have
$$
f'(x)=e^{x\log(1+\alpha^\frac{2}{1-2x})}\big[\log(1+\alpha^\frac{2}{1-2x})+x\{\log(1+\alpha^\frac{2}{1-2x})\}'\big],
$$
hence
$$
f'(0)=\log(1+\alpha^2).
$$
Next set $g(x)=\alpha^\frac{2x}{1-2x}$ to get $g'(0)=\log(\alpha^2)$. In the end the limit is
$$
\frac{f'(0)-g'(0)}{f'(0)}=\frac{\log(1+\alpha^2)-\log(\alpha^2)}{\log(1+\alpha^2)}=\frac{\log(1+\alpha^{-2})}{\log(1+\alpha^2)}.
$$
Quite interestingly, the pattern of this expression mimics that of the second fraction in the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a^{\frac{1}{n-1}}\left(\left[1+a^{-\frac{2n}{n-1}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2n}}-1\right)}{(1+a^{\frac{2n}{n-1}})^{\frac{1}{2n}}-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\left(\left[1+a^{-\frac{2n}{n-1}}\right]^{\frac{1}{2n}}-1\right)}{(1+a^{\frac{2n}{n-1}})^{\frac{1}{2n}}-1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2n}a^{-\frac{2n}{n-1}}}{\frac{1}{2n}a^{\frac{2n}{n-1}}}=\dfrac{1}{a^4}$$

Comment: Finally, I don't believe the $o(x)$ argument can be saved. For it, one needs the exponent fixed, but in our case it goes to $0$ also.

Comment: Oh,yes,I will edit it tomorrow,because I must go to bed